# blazor WASM create and download a file

Tags: c#, file, blazor

I have a class that can be serialized into a json file I want to allow users to download the json file.

How can I generate a file in memory and then have the browser download it ??

I guess I need to have a stream of some sort, but how do I make it download afterward?
I would love to avoid JS since I have no knowledge about it

Comment: So in newtonsoft `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` returns a string, so getting that into a text file by itself is very simple. As for allowing the file to be downloaded, [this article for ASP.NET](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/afenster/how-to-download-a-file-in-Asp-Net/) should be applicable here. Not sure what the exact Content-Type should be though, given that its a JSON text file, I'm assuming to prefer the typing used for .txt

Comment: I'm hosting the thing on github pages, will I be able to create the text file from the code there? Not saying I think it won't be possible, just trying to foresee difficulties. So if I understood you correctly I create a file, fill it with the string content then create a download tot that file?

Comment: I don't think this is best practice, but my inclination would be to include a temp directory in my project and essentially write and temporarily store the file to the temp dir, and then immediately delete it afterward. Now if you were on an actual server and you *know* for a fact that these files would get too big, then you definately would not want to do this. But JSON files are tiny, and as far as I know github pages won't kill you if you use up some of their space

Comment: If you could add some examples, I would prefer this solution over JS ones. But I really have no clue where to add all this code you likened in the article …

Comment: I have barely worked with Blazor myself, and I haven't actually attempted this myself even within ASP.NET which is what has stopped me from posting my own answer. To start off really simple I would say place this logic in a method within a `@code{}` block that binds as an event to the **intended download button**. Try it out and get it working that way. From there, then you can consider moving it down into your backend MVC/MVVM structure, if you are even using that for Blazor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres how I did it in my project with JS Interop and System.Text.Json. This code has not been used by me in a couple of months though and I can't test it right now. But it did work when I added it.

Blazor code:

```cs
@using System.Text.Json
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

...

async Task downloadObject(object objectToSave, string fileName)
{
    var obj = JsonSerializer.Serialize(objectToSave);
    var fileStream = new MemoryStream(new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(obj));
    using var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: fileStream);
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", fileName, streamRef);
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
window.downloadFileFromStream = async (fileName, contentStreamReference) => {
    const arrayBuffer = await contentStreamReference.arrayBuffer();
    const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
    anchorElement.href = url;

    if (fileName) {
        anchorElement.download = fileName;
    }

    anchorElement.click();
    anchorElement.remove();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid JS, but… Ended up doing this. Works like a charm.